# Selenium, unable to browse and update files

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I am doing an automation using selenium, I need an html code to click on the browse window (marked 1) and select the file (callform.txt) and update to the source filelist path [image: below is the image for the same]

Comment: I think Selenium may struggle to do this as the File Input dialog is outside the DOM?

Comment: You can try just sending the file path to the element, using .`SendKeys`, but if it doesn't work, you'll probably have to fish out a third party solution like AutoIT.

Answer (score 1):

You can use autoit.Just Download the autoit software from given link and install it.

[AutoIt Site](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Write a few lines script in autoit according to your need and call the compiled exe before the line which causes that window to appear.

The Autoit WIndow Info Tool will help you in identifying the ID and class for the desired controls

Answer (score 0):

Use Xpath of the search text box, try this

```
  <tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf/</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>assertTitle</td>
   <td>Online&nbsp;PDF&nbsp;Converter — Create&nbsp;PDF   &amp;&nbsp;Convert&nbsp;PDF&nbsp;to Word —Free!</td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=File1</td>
    <td>C:\Users\Downloads\xyz.doc</td>  // Path of file
   </tr>
```

[image: This is selenium scrpit check it work or not]

```
Check this Example, let me know
```

Comment: This will not work for me as we cant type in the field. We can only browse.

Answer (score 0):

To upload files:

1.use autoit tool-
a. Record the the part of the clicking the Browse Button and select the file.
b. Convert the AutoIt script into .exe.
c. Use the below script

```
String[] commands = new String[]{};
commands = new String[]{"C:\\Documents and Settings\\axtst079\\Desktop\\Hari1.exe"}; //location of the autoit executable
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
```

For more on Auto it refer 
http://automationtricks.blogspot.in/2010/09/how-to-upload-file-in-selenium.html

```
2.            uploadElement.findElement(By.id("uploader_browse")).click();
                uploadElement.sendKeys("C:\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\someimage.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

The upload window is a Windows component, you can not click on desired file using Selenium. The way to doing this is to use Autoit. Get the name of upload window and type the existing file name in "File name" input box. then on click the "Open" button. Here is the sample code -

```
WinGetHandle("Choose File to Upload") ;
ControlFocus("Choose File to Upload", "", "Edit1");
Send("Callform.txt");
ControlClick("Choose File to Upload", "", "Button1", "left", "1", "", "");
```

The "classnameNN(Edit1/Button1)" can be different, please check the "classnameNN" of your window by Autoit window info.

Answer (score 0):

You  can use Robot JAR file  here.
Using Robot JAR file you can use the keyboard short cut keys.